# Is there a static code analysis tool for Apex?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I know it's somewhat stupid to ask when I already know the answer. But I think this is of such a common interest that I want to also put it into Stackexchange.

---

Is there any tool for Ape which could do static code analysis of my Apex classes to answer questions like:

- Is my code overly complex or error prone?
- How many tests do I need to really cover all path?
- Is my code quality degrading over time?
- How much technical debt did we create in the past?

I know such tools exits for Java and .Net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To really be flexible we recently started porting the [famous Java Static code analyzer **PMD**](https://pmd.github.io/) to Apex. Other than the solution mentioned above, we made this an open-source project on Github (https://github.com/Up2Go/pmd).

We also [ported many of the original Java rules](https://github.com/Up2Go/pmd/issues/1) to Apex.

We are also building an open-source [CodeClimate engine](https://codeclimate.com/engines)  so you could not only analyze files on your local machine but also have code checked into your Github repos verified.

**We are looking for contributors who want to create new and better rules. If you need help just get in touch with robert.soesemann@up2go.com.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The force.com security scanner http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner  and its paid companion product from Checkmarx also does some code quality assessments as well.

Comment: Steven I disagree that this is static code analysis. It just checking if you adhere to the restrictions of Salesforce.com for getting something through the security review.

Comment: I disagree with your disagreement :)  

"Code Quality
The Force.com Security Source Scanner will detect the following 10+ common Apex coding and design issues:

DML statements inside loops
SOQL/SOSL inside loops
Hardcoding Trigger.new[0]
Hardcoding Trigger.old[0]
Queries with no Where clause or no LIMIT clause
Not bulkifying apex methods
Async (@future) methods inside loops
Hardcoding IDs
Multiple triggers on same object
Static Resource referencing"

Comment: The Force.com Security Source Scanner is production quality static analysis performed by Checkmarx engines. It performs control and dataflow analysis.